# Zend Framework 3 problem with redis caching

Tags: php, redis, zend-framework3

I am having a problem getting Redis caching working in my ZF3 application.

I have been trying to piece together how to do this from various websites, including SO and am really not sure if I am going the right way about this.

What I am doing so far is this:

In my global.php config file I have added :

```
...
'redis_cache' => [
    'adapter' => [
        'name' => 'redis',
        'options' => [
            'server' => [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6379,
            ]
        ]
    ],
]
...
```

In my controller I have

```
use Zend\Cache\StorageFactory;
```

and then inside a method I am trying to test the cache using

```
$redis = StorageFactory::factory ($this->config['redis_cache']);


    if ($redis->hasItem ('mykey'))
    {
        $value = $redis->getItem('mykey');
    }

    echo 'value = ' . $value;
```

This is not getting the value. However if I do a print_r() on $redis I can see the Redis object has been created.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is of help to anyone else, this is the solution I found.

Firstly, I needed to install zend-serializer, I already had zend-cache installed.

```
php composer require zendframework/zend-serializer
```

Then in /config/autoload/global.php I added

```
'caches' => [
    'RedisCache' => [
        'adapter' => [
            'name'    => Redis::class,
            'options' => [
                'server' => [
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => '6379',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'plugins' => [
            [
                'name' => 'serializer',
                'options' => [
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

In /config/application.config.php I added

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Redis::class => InvokableFactory::class
    ]
]
```

Finally, In my controller factory I set up the dependency injection like this

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $cache = $container->get('RedisCache');

    return new IndexController($cache);
}
```

To use the caching in my controller I added the caching to my constructor

```
public function __construct($cache)
{
    $this->cache = $cache;
}
```

and in a method:

```
$this->cache->setItem('foo', 'bar');
echo $this->cache->getItem('foo');
```

Comment: Did it really speed up the website? And what do you mean with the last? In every action method in controller i have to use that?

Comment: Hi Jilco. I was mainly using the Redis cache for storing PHP sessions. This was because the site was hosted in a cloud environment on MS Azure using scalesets so there wasn't any effect on the speed of the site in my case. 

If you are referring to $this->cache->setItem() and $this->cache->getItem() they would only need to be used in methods where you wanted to either store some data or retrieve it from Redis.